# Understanding Bash's Read-a-File Command Substitution

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, command-substitution

I am trying to understand how exactly Bash treats the following line:

```
$(< "$FILE")
```

According to the Bash man page, this is equivalent to:

```
$(cat "$FILE")
```

and I can follow the line of reasoning for this second line. Bash performs variable expansion on `$FILE`, enters command substitution, passes the value of `$FILE` to `cat`, cat outputs the contents of `$FILE` to standard output, command substitution finishes by replacing the entire line with the standard output resulting from the command inside, and Bash attempts to execute it like a simple command.

However, for the first line I mentioned above, I understand it as: Bash performs variable substitution on `$FILE`, Bash opens `$FILE` for reading on standard input, ***somehow standard input is copied to standard output***, command substitution finishes, and Bash attempts to execute the resulting standard output.

Can someone please explain to me how the contents of `$FILE` goes from stdin to stdout?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The `<` isn't directly an aspect of [bash command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst).  It is a redirection operator (like a pipe), which some shells allow without a command (POSIX does not specify this behavior).

Perhaps it would be more clear with more spaces:

```
echo $( < $FILE )
```

this is *effectively** the same as the more POSIX-safe

```
echo $( cat $FILE )
```

... which is also effectively*

```
echo $( cat < $FILE )
```

Let's start with that last version.  This runs `cat` with no arguments, which means it will read from standard input.  `$FILE` is redirected into standard input due to the `<`, so `cat` puts its contents are put into standard output.  The `$(command)` subsitution then pushes `cat`'s output into arguments for `echo`.

In `bash` (but not in the POSIX standard), you can use `<` without a command.  `bash` (and `zsh` and `ksh` but not `dash`) will interpret that as if `cat <`, though without invoking a new subprocess.  As this is native to the shell, it is faster than literally running the external command `cat`.  *****This is why I say "effectively the same as."

Comment: So in the last paragraph when you say "`bash` will interpret that as `cat filename`", do you mean this behavior is specific to command substitution? Because if I run `< filename` by itself, bash does not cat it out. It will output nothing and return me back to a prompt.

Comment: A command is still needed.  @cuonglm altered my original text from `cat < filename` to `cat filename` which I oppose and may revert.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers so far, Adam. But if bash is interpreting `< filename` as `cat < filename` in the context of command substitution, why does the man page say `$(< file)` is faster? This statement, from the start, led me to believe cat was somehow redundant. This is clearly not the case if what you say is true. Or maybe I missed something.

Comment: @cuonglm, I have reverted your edit.  `cat < -` does indeed fail, but `-` also does not work with `< -` so it is consistent.

Comment: @StanleyYu, `$(< file)` is faster because it doesn't spawn a new process (`cat`).  `<` is a builtin.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. So it's basically doing the same thing as `cat < filename` but with the added benefit of staying within bash. Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation (especially the second sentence) is wrong. No pipe is involved in `<$FILE`. A pipe is involved in the command substitution `$(…)` only.

Comment: @Gilles: I thought the term "pipe" referred to any redirection operator rather than just `|`. I have rephrased given the verbiage in the man page for `dash`.  With that clarification, I do not believe that the term "pipe" (or "pipeline") is relevant w.r.t. `$()` command substitution.

Comment: A pipe is a type of file. The shell operator `|` creates a pipe between two subprocesses (or, with some shells, from a subprocess to the shell's standard input). The shell operator `$(…)` creates a pipe from a subprocess to the shell itself (not to its standard input). The shell operator `<` does not involve a pipe, it only opens a file and moves the file descriptor to standard input.

Comment: Oh, also bash doesn't actually launch `cat`, it does the job internally.

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks for explaining the additional intricacies of the shell and confirming that bash does it internally, Gilles. And, yes, I understand that cat is not called. When Adam said "is the same as" I understood it  to mean something more along the lines of "provides the same result as", not literally `<` = `cat <`.

Comment: @AdamKatz: No, `cat filename` will fail with filename starts with `-`, `cat < filename` doesn't.

Comment: @AdamKatz: And also `<` is not a builtin in bash, it's redirection operator.

Comment: @AdamKatz: I mean `cat <filename` in my first editing, maybe I was sleepy.

Comment: @cuonglm:  Your edits are not helping.  The fact that `cat -file` will fail while `cat < -file` will not is unrelated.  `<` is built into bash.  While it's not a builtin command, it is also not an external command.  I'll use the term "native" instead.

Comment: @AdamKatz: That's why I said `<filename` is equivalent to `cat < -filename` isntead of `cat -file`. Just want to insist `cat $FILE` # `<$FILE`.

Comment: `< file` is not the same as `cat < file` (except in `zsh` where it's like `$READNULLCMD < file`). `< file` is perfectly POSIX and just opens `file` for reading and then does nothing (so `file` is close straight away). It's `$(< file)` or `\`< file\`` that is a special operator of `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash` (and the behaviour is left unspecified in POSIX). See [my answer](/a/368663) for details.

Comment: To put @StéphaneChazelas’s comment in another light: to a first approximation, `$(cmd1) $(cmd2)` will typically be the same as `$(cmd1; cmd2)`.   But look at the case where `cmd2` is `< file`.   If we say `$(cmd1; < file)`, the file is not read, but, with `$(cmd1) $(< file)`, it is.   So it is incorrect to say that `$(< file)` is just an ordinary case of `$(command)` with a command of `< file`.   `$(< …)` is a *special case* of command substitution, and not a normal usage of redirection.

Answer (score 27):

`$(<file)` (also works with `` `<file` `` as well as `${<file;}` in ksh93) is a special operator of the Korn shell copied by `zsh` and `bash`. It does look a lot like command substitution but it's not really.

In POSIX shells, a simple command is:

```
< file var1=value1 > file2 cmd 2> file3 args 3> file4
```

All parts are optional, you can have redirections only, command only, assignment only or combinations.

If there are redirections but no command, the redirections are performed (so a `> file` would open and truncate `file`), but then nothing happens. So

```
< file
```

Opens `file` for reading, but then nothing happens as there's no command. So the `file` is then closed and that's it. If `$(< file)` was a simple *command substitution*, then it would expand to nothing.

In the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03), in `$(script)`, if `script` consists only of redirections, that *produces unspecified results*. That's to allow that special behaviour of the Korn shell.

In ksh (here tested with `ksh93u+`), if the script consists of one and only one *simple command* (though comments are allowed before and after) that consists only of redirections (no command, no assignment) and if the first redirection is a stdin (fd 0) input only (`<`, `<<` or `<<<`) redirection, so:

- `$(< file)`
- `$(0< file)`
- `$(<&3)` (also `$(0>&3)` actually as that's in effect the same operator)
- `$(< file > foo 2> $(whatever))`

but not:

- `$(> foo < file)`
- nor `$(0<> file)`
- nor `$(< file; sleep 1)`
- nor `$(< file; < file2)`

then

- all but the first redirection are ignored (they are parsed away)
- and it expands to the content of the file/heredoc/herestring (or whatever can be read from the file descriptor if using things like `<&3`) minus the trailing newline characters.

as if using `$(cat < file)` except that

- the reading is done internally by the shell and not by `cat`
- no pipe nor extra process is involved
- as a consequence of the above, since the code inside is not run in a subshell, any modification remain thereafter (as in `$(<${file=foo.txt})` or `$(<file$((++n)))`)
- read errors (though not errors while opening files or duplicating file descriptors) are silently ignored.

In `zsh`, it's the same except that that special behaviour is only triggered when there's only one file input redirection (`<file` or `0< file`, no `<&3`, `<<<here`, `< a < b`...)

However, except when emulating other shells, in `< file`
that is when there's only one input redirection without commands, outside of command substitution, `zsh` runs the `$READNULLCMD` (a pager by default), and when there are more redirections or redirections other than `< file` (`<&3`, `<<<text`, `<a <b`, `>file`, `<a >b` ...) the `$NULLCMD` (`cat` by default), so even if `$(<&3)` is not recognized as that special operator, it will still work like in `ksh` by invoking `cat` to do it.

However while `ksh`'s `$(< a < b)` would expand to the contents of `a`, in `zsh`, it expands to the content of `a` *and `b`* (or just `b` if the `multios` option is disabled), `$(< a > b)` would copy `a` to `b` and expand to nothing, etc.

`bash`  has a similar operator but with a few differences:

- comments are allowed before but not after:

  ```
  echo "$(
     # getting the content of file
     < file)"
  ```

  works but:

  ```
  echo "$(< file
     # getting the content of file
  )"
  ```

  expands to nothing.
- like in `zsh`, only one file stdin redirection, though there's no fall back to a `$READNULLCMD`, so `$(<&3)`, `$(< a < b)` do perform the redirections but expand to nothing.
- for some reason, while `bash` does not invoke `cat`, it still forks a process that feeds the content of the file through a pipe making it much less of an optimisation than in other shells. It's in effect like a `$(cat < file)` where `cat` would be a builtin `cat`.
- as a consequence of the above, any change made within are lost afterwards (in the `$(<${file=foo.txt})`, mentioned above for instance, that `$file` assignment is lost afterwards).

In `bash`, `IFS= read -rd '' var < file`  (also works in `zsh`) is a more effective way  to read the content of a *text* file into a variable. It also has the benefit of preserving the trailing newline characters. See also `$mapfile[file]` in `zsh` (in the `zsh/mapfile` module and only for regular files) which also works with binary files.

Note that the pdksh-based variants of `ksh` have a few variations compared to ksh93. Of interest, in `mksh` (one of those pdksh-derived shells), in

```
var=$(<<'EOF'
That's multi-line
test with *all* sorts of "special"
characters
EOF
)
```

is optimised in that the content of the here document (without the trailing newline characters) is expanded without a temporary file or pipe being used as is otherwise the case for here documents, which makes it an effective multi-line quoting syntax.

To be portable to all versions of `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash`, best is to limit to only `$(<file)` avoiding comments and bearing in mind that modifications to variables made within may or may not be preserved.

Comment: Is it correct that `$(<)` is an operator on filenames? Is `<` in  `$(<)` a redirection operator, or not an operator on its own, and must be part of the entire operator  `$(<)`?

Comment: @Tim, it doesn't matter much how you want to call them. `$(<file)` is meant to expand to the content of `file` in a similar way as `$(cat < file)` would. How it's done varies from shell to shell which is described at length in the answer. If you like, you can say that it's a special operator that is triggered when what looks like a command substitution (syntactically) contains what looks like a single stdin redirection (syntactically), but again with caveats and variations depending on the shell as listed here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Fascinating, as usual; I’ve bookmarked this.  So, `n<&m` and `n>&m` do the same thing? I didn’t know that, but I guess it’s not too surprising.

Comment: @Scott, yes, they both do a `dup(m, n)`. I can see some evidence of ksh86 using stdio and some `fdopen(fd, "r" or "w")`, so it might have mattered then. But using stdio in a shell makes little sense, so I don't expect you'll find any modern shell where that will make a difference. One difference is that `>&n` is `dup(n, 1)` (short for `1>&n`), while `<&n` is `dup(n, 0)` (short for `0<&n`).

Comment: Right. Except, of course, the two-argument form of the file descriptor duplication call is called `dup2()`; `dup()` takes only one argument and, like `open()`, uses the lowest available file descriptor. (Today I learned that [there is a `dup3()` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html).)

Comment: @Scott, yes sorry, see also [Significance of arrows symbols in duplicating/closing file descriptors under bash](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/64995)

Comment: Not sure if Bash's process substitution `<(list)` is portable: `$ cat <(echo test)` produces output `test`.

Comment: @eelghEEz, that's another feature of ksh copied by zsh and bash (not pdksh). That's in effect the reverse: get a file out of string instead of a string out of a file.

Comment: Is this documented? Particularly in the `bash` docs.

Answer (score 9):

Because `bash` does it internally for you, expanded the filename and cats the file to standard output, like if you were to do `$(cat < filename)`. It's a bash feature, maybe you need to look into the `bash` source code to know exactly how it works.

Here the the function to handle this feature (From `bash` source code, file `builtins/evalstring.c`):

```
/* Handle a $( < file ) command substitution.  This expands the filename,
   returning errors as appropriate, then just cats the file to the standard
   output. */
static int
cat_file (r)
     REDIRECT *r;
{
  char *fn;
  int fd, rval;

  if (r->instruction != r_input_direction)
    return -1;

  /* Get the filename. */
  if (posixly_correct && !interactive_shell)
    disallow_filename_globbing++;
  fn = redirection_expand (r->redirectee.filename);
  if (posixly_correct && !interactive_shell)
    disallow_filename_globbing--;

  if (fn == 0)
    {
      redirection_error (r, AMBIGUOUS_REDIRECT);
      return -1;
    }

  fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0)
    {
      file_error (fn);
      free (fn);
      return -1;
    }

  rval = zcatfd (fd, 1, fn);

  free (fn);
  close (fd);

  return (rval);
}
```

A note that `$(<filename)` is not exactly equivalent to `$(cat filename)`; the latter will fail if the filename starts with a dash `-`.

`$(<filename)` was originally from `ksh`, and was added to `bash` from `Bash-2.02`.

Comment: `cat filename` will fail if the filename starts with a dash because cat accepts options.  You can work around that on most modern systems with `cat -- filename`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash 3.2 snippet that shows the difference, explained:

- Use strace to follow processes and show execve calls `strace -f -e trace=execve`
- Run bash reading commands from string `bash -c` - with and without `/bin/cat`
- Diff the output in side by side mode in 80 columns to fit here `diff -y -W 80`

You can see the extra `execve(/bin/cat...)` on the right side of the diff:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.25(1)-release
$ echo "hi" >/tmp/f
$ strace -f -e trace=execve /bin/bash -c 'echo $(</tmp/f)'          >/tmp/no_cat 2>&1
$ strace -f -e trace=execve /bin/bash -c 'echo $(/bin/cat </tmp/f)' >/tmp/wi_cat 2>&1
$ diff -y -W 80 /tmp/no_cat /tmp/wi_cat
execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c | execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c
Process 24253 attached (waiting for p | Process 24256 attached (waiting for p
Process 24253 resumed (parent 24252 r | Process 24256 resumed (parent 24255 r
Process 24253 detached                | Process 24257 attached (waiting for p
                                      > Process 24257 resumed (parent 24256 r
                                      > Process 24256 suspended
                                      > [pid 24257] execve("/bin/cat", ["/bin
                                      > Process 24256 resumed
                                      > Process 24257 detached
                                      > [pid 24256] --- SIGCHLD (Child exited
                                      > Process 24256 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) --   --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) --
hi                                      hi
```