# Is `$(< file)` completely bash, or does `$(< file)` really depend on `cat`?

Tags: bash

From Bash Manual:

> The command substitution
>   `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.

`cat` is from coreutils, instead of a bash builtin command.
So I am surprised that the bash manual would mention something outside bash, such as `cat`.

Is `$(< file)` really a shorthand of `$(cat file)`?

Is `$(< file)` completely bash, or does `$(< file)` really depend on `cat`?

If `$(< file)` is completely bash, and doesn't depend on `cat`,

- is `< file` a redirection or a command or both (a command with a redirection and an empty command name)?
- how can `< file` (a command with a redirection and an empty command name) output to stdout?

Thanks.

Comment: See [Understanding Bash's Command Substitution](/q/189749) but beware the accepted answer there is wrong

Answer (score 3):

Update: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368663/145784 for a full discussion of unix operators, such as `$(<`, in different shells.

`$(< file)` is completely bash.  The statement `< file` takes the file, and redirects it to `stdin` of the command it is invoked with.  In this case, `$()` is a form of command substitution, so it is used as a substitute for a command.  It takes the input it receives, and converts it into a variable suitable to be used in a command.  Since it does not invoke an outside program `cat`, it is therefore faster.

To output this variable to stdout, you would simply run:

```
echo $(< file)
```

Comment: Thanks. is `< file` a redirection or a command or both (a command with a redirection and an empty command name)?
how can `< file`  output to stdout without a command name? We need a command name which performs the output operation, right?

Comment: Give me a moment.  I just submit the post before finishing it, to have something out there while I continue answering the question.  Let me know whether this answers your question now.

Comment: I mention output to stdout, not because I want to know how to output to stdout (which you answered by `echo $(< file)`) . It is because command substitution `$(some-command)`  assumes the command inside `$(...)` outputs to stdout, so that command substitution captures its stdout output and then expands to the captured. If a command doesn't output to stdout, how can command substitution work with the command?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I updated the post to address this question (which I didn't glean from the original post, sorry).  Let me know if this makes sense now.

Comment: Thanks. A redirection like `< file` can apply only to a command. `$()` isn't a command, and even if it were a command, shouldn't `< file` follow `$()` instead of appearing inside?

Comment: No, that's not correct. `$(<` is a special operator. It's not the same as running `< file` in a command substitution which would expand to nothing.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not so sure about that.  I just ran `echo \`< file\``, which is the other form of command substitution, and it seems to have executed just fine...

Comment: Yes both `\`<` and `$(<`. If it was normal command-substitution, you'd need no output at all, like when you do `< b.sh` (in shells other than zsh). See my answer to the duplicate question for details.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh, wow, you should post something to have your answer as the accepted one on this post too.

Comment: Well, this one is now closed as duplicate. You could correct yours here and add a link to mine there for further details.