# How do I cut text from one file and replace it with text in another file?

Tags: bash, sed, macintosh, cut, paste

I have a text file, *mac.txt*, with one line that looks like this:

```
4a:38:61:e1:71:7c
```

... and I have a bash script, *mask.sh*, that simply changes my MAC address:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo macchanger -m 16:dx:0b:rc:4a:32 wlan0
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to write a bash script that will copy the MAC address from *mac.txt* and replace it with the MAC address in *mask.sh*, so that it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo macchanger -m 4a:38:61:e1:71:7c wlan0
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

I've tried a couple variations with sed, cut, and paste but am too embarrassed to show what I'd tried. I'm still pretty new to this.

Comment: Welcome! I would say that a simple `sudo macchanger -m $(cat mac.txt) wlan0` will work.

Comment: Wow! I was way overthinking this. Thank you, sir. That does exactly what I need it to!

Comment: ... or even `$(< mac.txt)`. See for example [Understanding Bash's Read-a-File Command Substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368663/65304)

Comment: Thanks! Checking that out now!

Answer (score 1):

As [schrodigerscatcuriosity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/338177/schrodigerscatcuriosity) commented, you could use bash's command substitution:

```
sudo macchanger -m $(cat mac.txt) wlan0
```

or, since you're just using `cat` on a file:

```
sudo macchanger -m $(< mac.txt) wlan0
```

These are explained in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) under Command Substitution.