# bash substitution within substitution

Tags: bash

My goal is to do

```
filename=user2.json
userJson=${cat ${filename} | jq}
```

This obviously don't work.

---

According to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/69002/220237), this should work (but it doesn't):

```
  filename=user2.json
  eval "userJson=\${cat $filename | jq}"
```

`Error: ${cat user2.json | jq}: bad substitution`

---

`cat user2.json | jq` works fine on its own

---

Here are other combinations I tried that didn't work:

1.

```
  filename=user2.json
  eval "userJson=\${cat $(filename) | jq}"
```

`Error: ${cat  | jq}: bad substitution`

2.

```
  filename=user2.json
  eval "userJson=\${cat '${filename}' | jq}"
```

`Error: ${cat 'user2.json' | jq}: bad substitution`

Comment: `userJson=$(cat "${filename}" | jq .)`

Comment: @HatLess Thank you! Finally, it works! ( I don't know why you added the dot after "jq" though, seems unnecessary.)

Comment: This seems to be mostly a repeat of the issue in your previous question ([Call command with one argument being the result of cat'ing a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715141)).  The only difference is where the command substitution is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong brackets:

```
filename=user2.json
userJson=$(jq <"$filename")
```

Comment: Surely `jq` takes filename args ? (I just deleted my UUOC comment.)

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Rather `jq . -- "$filename"` (`jq -- . "$filename"` doesn't work!) and even then it doesn't work for a file called `-`, while `jq < "$filename"` works regardless of what `$filename` contains and also has the advantage of not running `jq` if the file can't be opened (and in that case gives an error message that's consistent regardless of which command is being redirected and with many shells also give the line number within the script where the error occurred).