# How to read files of kind "-diary.txt-" using echo?

Tags: shell, echo

I have a file named "-diary.txt-", I need to get it's content. When trying to read it using `echo < "-diary.txt-"`, it returns a blank string. I did some research, and came up with this: `echo "$(<-diary.txt-)"`. I tested it out on my computer, and it worked perfectly, but when I logged on the server, it still returns a blank string. I can only use these commands:
`. : [ [[ alias bg break cd chdir command continue echo eval exec exit export false fg getopts hash help history jobs kill let    local printf pwd read readonly return set shift source test times   trap true type ulimit umask unalias unset wait`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(<file)` is a special construct of the Korn shell now also supported by a few others including `zsh` and `bash`, but that's about it (see [Understanding Bash's Read-a-File Command Substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189749)).

On POSIX-like shells that don't support it, that would just expand to nothing.

Among your list of commands, only `read` seems to be able to `read` input in a useful way¹. `echo` doesn't read anything, it just outputs its arguments after option processing and transformation.

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$file" ]; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < -diary.txt-
```

Should read the contents one line at a time and print each line with [`printf` (not `echo` which can't be used for arbitrary data)](/q/65803). All three commands used there (`[`, `read` and `printf`) are in your list, the `while; do; done` and `||` are language constructs of the shell.

That should work as long as the file doesn't contain NUL characters. If the file didn't end in a newline character, that will add it on output.

That assumes the shell is POSIX-sh-like, but given that list of commands, many of which are typically `sh` builtins, that's more than likely.

---

<sup>¹, `.` aka `source` can also read files, but it also tries to interpret what it reads as shell code, so that won't be useful.</sup>